# Load a .PS1 file into current session without simulating user input?

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I have this file called `Local_Paths.txt` . Its just a text file full of paths:

```
C:\Temp\README.md
C:\Temp\README.md
C:\Temp\object_lifetime_management.md
C:\Temp\object_reference.md
...
...
...
```

The paths are being logged there, in real time as I interact with folders and files, in file manager and other tools.

The purpose of this `Local_Paths.txt` is for a module I made in powershell. For example I can quicly call up Terminal and pipe the 5 most recent `.Md` files into this module.

I have the file loaded into a variable in my `$Profile`:

```
cls
$LocalPaths = Get-Content "C:\Users\...\Documents\Local_Paths.txt"
```

On the rare case I have to boot up Powershell, this works fine. The problem I have is that I always have a Powershell session minimised on the taskbar.

So I am constantly either  `. $Profile` my entire profile, which is quite a heavy file. or just declaring  a `$LocalPaths = Get-Content "C:\Users\...\Documents\Local_Paths.txt"`.

This proccess just kills the purpose of my module (Less hand wringling, more automation)

I am wondering is there a way to inject powershell code into the current  session through a `.Ps1`  script or even through the `wt` command?

so that when I press the hotkey to focus Powershell this script to load the txt file gets executed first.

I did go through the Windows Terminal page for the `Actions` command. This is still user simulation though.

---

I have taken the liberty to cross post this question on other forums as well. Any help or just pointing me in the right direction would appreciated.

Comment: Maybe not quite what you're looking for but could be a start.  You can set a custom key combination to run a scriptblock using `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler`.  Something like this should work for you `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord "Ctrl+j" -ScriptBlock {$Global:LocalPaths = C:\Users\...\Documents\Local_Paths.txt"}`.  If you add that to your profile it will be available each session and easy to quickly do anytime you need.  You might want to double-check that whatever key chord you choose is not in use first using `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the value of `$LocalPaths` to always reflect the latest content of your `Local_Paths.txt` file.

Since you need *some* identifier to refer to this content, you could use a *function* instead, which reads the file *on every invocation*, and you can place that in your `$PROFILE` file:

```bash
# Note: I'm using a name that follows PowerShell's naming convention here,
#       but you're free to choose your own, possibly shorter name.
#       The use of @args means that you can pass arguments through
#       to the Get-Content call, such as -Tail 5
function Get-LocalPaths { 
  Get-Content -LiteralPath 'C:\Users\...\Documents\Local_Paths.txt' @args
}
```

If reading the file every time the function is called is too costly, you could implement a caching mechanism that only reloads the file if its `.LastWriteTime` property has changed.